# api.DeviceException in react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, failed-installation

While running my react native app i'm getting this error .
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Comment: Try to uninstall the app on your phone first then try installing again

Comment: The app is installted but i'm getting the error wp on screen

Comment: can't find the variable wp.

Comment: what is error wp?

Comment: yes in my device screen i'm getting can't find variable:wp

Comment: This error comes after opening the app? what is the full message of the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179084/discussion-between-aguthadeus-and-shabnam-singh).